# What does this tag mean?

Tags: html

Hello I am new on this site and I would like to start with a banal answer. I begin from less time to do something in html.
I would like to know something: what is the function of this tag? (!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> ).
Thanks to everyone that will going to answer me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Actual Use of Doctype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865944/actual-use-of-doctype)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is DOCTYPE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414891/what-is-doctype)

Answer (score 2):

The `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration must be the very first thing in your HTML document, before the `<html>` tag.
The `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration is not an HTML tag; it is an instruction to
See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Stas Kovalenko